# Explain the difference between near, far and huge pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between far pointer and near pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/difference-between-far-pointer-and-near-pointer-in-c)

I searched in GOOGLE for the difference between these three pointers. But I found out the difference between any of the two pointers.

Can you give Detailed Explanation of this please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Pointer_sizes

Answer (score 22):

The differences are only relevant on `16 bit intel architectures`.

As far as virtual addresses is concerned, It has two components - a selector and an offset.

The **selector** is an index into a table of base addresses and **offset** is added onto that base address.

**near** pointers don't have a selector - they have an `implied selector`. They can access 64k off the virtual address space.

**far** pointers have an `explicit selector`. However when you do pointer arithmetic on them the `selector isn't modified`.

**huge** pointers have an `explicit selector`. When you do pointer arithmetic on them though `the selector can change`.

Please Refer this link for more info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/103115/near-vs-far-vs-huge-pointers/?cmt=11086#answer1

Comment: Aargh! I'm starting to remember all this stuff! (All the stuff with memory models too.) Make it go away! I moved to developing for 32-bit flat architectures only for good reason…

Answer (score 4):

Near, far, and huge pointers aren't part of standard C; they are/were an extension put in by several vendors to deal with segmented memory architectures.  Karthik's answer gives much more detail.