# Why Is The Size of ptr3 2?

Tags: c, pointers

//The output for this code is observed to be 4 4 2 ? I dont get why is it 2 for ptr3?please help

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char huge *near *far *ptr1;
char near *far *huge *ptr2;
char far *huge *near *ptr3;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sizeof(ptr1), sizeof(ptr2), sizeof(ptr3)); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What system? What compiler?  That's not standard C syntax.

Comment: `near`, `far`, and `huge` suggest that it's some sort of ancient, obsolete DOS-based compiler. Borland C, perhaps?

Comment: The standard defines `sizeof(char)` to be `1`.  You get no other guarantees.

Comment: In that case, the answer is "go read your compiler documentation".

Comment: @E F: What made you believe that size `2` for that pointer is something unusual to the point that you even asked this question? Why not `2`? In a way it is like asking why `2 + 2` equals `4`. How does one answer a question like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`near`, `far`, and `huge` pointers are non-standard.

In implementations that support them (usually for very old x86 systems), a specific location in memory can be specified by a segment and an offset. A `near` pointer contains only an offset, leaving the segment implicit. Thus it requires less space than a `far` pointer.

Modern compilers do not use any of these keywords. I suggest you find yourself a newer compiler; there are plenty of free ones available.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1749904/827263) for more information.

Incidentally, printf's `"%d"` format requires an argument of type `int`; `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, which is a different type. You can change your `printf` call to:

```
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", (int)sizeof ptr1, (int)sizeof ptr2, (int)sizeof ptr3);
```

(The modern way to do that is:

```
printf("%zu, %zu, %zu\n", sizeof ptr1, sizeof ptr2, sizeof ptr3);
```

but an implementation that supports `near` and `far` pointers isn't likely to be modern enough to support `"%zu"`, which was introduced in C99.)

Comment: or rather use %zu ? (provided he updates to C99 compliant compiler...)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: An implementation that supports `near` and `far` pointers is unlikely to support `"%zu"`.

Comment: thought of it 1 minutes later :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how widespread this is, but smaller embedded platforms (in the pre-smartphone sense) sometimes have very limited choice of compilers, and these compilers could well use the near/far keywords.  But yeah, +1, I think you nailed the answer by saying near pointers are smaller.

Comment: @KeithThompson Imagine platforms like AVR AT(x)mega etc - they have kind of `near`/`far` and nevertheless are (partially) C99-compliant...

Answer (score 1):

this `far` `near` and `huge` are the concepts used in old DOS-compilers.

[For more you can see this link.](http://www.thecareerplus.com/?page=resources&cat=10&subCat=25&qNo=21)

Which will explain everything about how are these implemented internally.
Due to this implementation you are getting the size like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to remove a layer of confusion, so you can use the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947376/509868).

Declaration of a `near` pointer looks like this:

```
type near* variable;
```

Or like this:

```
near type* variable;
```

Where `type` is any type. In your example, someone is trying to confuse you because `type` is itself a pointer type: `char far *huge *`. However, no matter what it points to, a `near` pointer occupies 2 bytes.

(I guess someone is trying to confuse you on purpose because there is no chance such constructs appear in real code)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an old compailer (may be turboc c).Latest compiler not support this functionality.

**near** pointers don't have a selector - they have an implied selector. They can access 64k off the virtual address space on a 286 and earlier and 4Gb of the addresss space on a 386 or later.

**far** pointers have an explicit selector. However when you do pointer arithmetic on them the selector isn't modified.

**huge** pointers have an explicit selector. When you do pointer arithmetic on them though the selector can change.