# In c language there is a concept of far pointer, but still it is not applicable using gcc compiler. Is there any way to implement far pointer in c?

Tags: gcc

In c language there is a concept of far pointer, but still it is not applicable using gcc compiler. Is there any way to implement far pointer in c using gcc compiler ? If there is any misconception related to far pointer please make it clear to me......

Comment: `far` pointers do not exist in standard [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). It is (was) a vendor specific extension.

Answer (score 5):

`Far` and `Near` pointers are applicable in 16-bit x86 architectures. So you may find the concept applicable in ancient compilers like Turbo C which are written for old l6-bit architecture but not in the modern compilers like GCC.

[What is the difference between far pointers and near pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/difference-between-far-pointer-and-near-pointer-in-c)
explains in more detail with regards to what they are.