# how to enable __far in gcc cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am having some trouble compiling my code having __far.

I have read that __far is not a c standard keyword.

furthermore, this is in relation to the use of rl78 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

C Implementations for architectures with [non-flat address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation), usually had those [two pointer "classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/what-is-the-difference-between-far-pointers-and-near-pointers):

- near pointers that store the offset within a memory segment
- far pointers that additionally specify what segment

Many compilers implemented the latter using a non-standard `__far` specifier. The 16-bit x86 used to be such an architecture.

But Cygwin is only available for 32 bit x86 and x86_64 versions of Windows. And on those there is no concept of near and far pointer anymore.

In order to compile your code, you will need to strip away the `__far`s and hope that the code itself isn't too tightly [coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability#Effort_to_port_source_code) to your original architecture.

Comment: thank you, how do you suggest that __far to be removed? what alternatives do you suggest rather than __far to be used?

Comment: Just remove it. e.g. by compiling with `-D__far=""`.