# far pointer declaration in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers

I have a far pointer declaration in this way:

```
char far *p;
```

But visual studio 2008 give me

```
error C2146: missing ';' before identifier 'p'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which platform are you compiling for?  `far` pointers were used back in the olden days, but are not relevant on modern platforms.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/what-is-the-difference-between-far-pointers-and-near-pointers

Comment: I'm compiling for Win 7. Thanks @cdarke for the link; I understood that there is no need now for far or near pointer; am I correct?

Comment: There might be a need if you are crossing--compiling for a 16-bit platform, but for Win 7, no.  Where did you get the idea from that you needed a far pointer?  It could be that you are using an old source that won't work any more.

Comment: Normally the Windows header files define `far` as expanding to nothing (`#define far`). Did you include `windows.h` in your source code? If you cannot (or don't want) to include `windows.h`, you can just add `#define far` in your file or whatever header.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling for old src code; It works by defining far to nothing. Please make it in a different answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`far` was a keyword in the 16 bit Microsoft compiler (and possibly other old compilers). Nowadays in the 32/64 bit world this keyword has become obsolete and useless.

Normally the Windows header files define `far` as expanding to nothing.

If you include `windows.h` your code should compile.

If you cannot or don't want to include `windows.h`, you can just add `#define far` in your file or whatever appropriate header file of your project.

Or best remove `far` manually from your source files.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard C syntax.
This was an added feature for < 32-bit compilers.

They are not needed and thus not supported on the modern compilers.

The implementation of this pointers may vary from compiler to a compiler.
The standard Microsoft compiler should not support this feature and should give you an error as it does. There might be a specific compiler for a specific hardware which extends the language to give you this feature.